# Why does the Google API not work in my Universal Windows App?

Tags: javascript, windows, google-api, win-universal-app, uwp

Error: *0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'setApiKey' of undefined or null reference*

Hello I'm desperatly trying to get this to work on my Universal Windows App. There is a sample for Googles URL shortener with instructions on how to use the API.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples

All of this works when I run this in my Browser, but as soon as I start running this in my Universal Windows App, it won't work. I figured that it had something to do with the security of the UWP, inline skripts arent allowed and you can't load scripts from the web normally. You have to use a webview to load scripts from the web so I did this with this webview:

```
<x-ms-webview id="UrlShortenerWebview"src="ms-appx-web:///Pages/URLShortener/URLShortener.html" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black;"></x-ms-webview>
```

This is my URL Shortener html file:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title></title>

 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>
  function appendResults(text) {
   var results = document.getElementById('results');
   results.appendChild(document.createElement('P'));
   results.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  }

  function makeRequest() {
   var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.get({
    'shortUrl': 'http://goo,gl/fbsS'
   });
   request.then(function (response) {
    appendResults(response.result.longUrl);
   }, function (reason) {
    console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
   });
  }
  function init() {
   gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyCzBnER6KmLiO2ZBIycZIPCEQEXxIrHnR0');
   gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1').then(makeRequest)
  }
  gapi.load("client", init);
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Error: *0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'setApiKey' of undefined or null reference*

I have no idea why that happens or what else I can do to fix this. Is it even possible to use the google api in windows apps???

Comment: This is an NPE essentially. Debug your code and figure out how a `null` is making its way into your code.

Comment: I don't know how. When I console log gapi.client it turns out to be undefined. is it because of the gapi.load function, that the client object is not being created? Even when I dont use the gapi.load function and just load the api with the ?onload=init I get the same error message

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4068779/rob-caplan-msft)'s comments in your MSDN case: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/bd101515-212b-4366-b60d-2807b2783f62

Rob mentioned two choices: calling local js files if Google permits it, or taking full control and stream your content to your `x-ms-webview` with `navigateToLocalStreamUri` method.